# Is there a rule to join lines based on a rule notepad++

Tags: notepad++, rules

I have a notepad++ file containing tens of thousands of lines.

Each entry in my import program must have each field separated by a delimiter.  When bringing the information over into notepad++ I have an issue where it detects carriage returns from excel and places them into the text which the import program won't read.

I am positive that each row has fields separated by commas, these fields have no character limit, and the only field that is a constant is the first field (date).

Each line in notepad++ needs to look like this

Date,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF

However, something in the copy paste over is causing these fields to insert carriage returns

I.e. Date, A,

B, C, D,

E, F,
G,
H, I, J etc.

Unfortunately there is not a line that is always affected in each case.

Is there anyway, rule, that will draw each of these up so that all lines that start with a date will be joined with the lines below it until there occurs another date?

Comment: Please [edit] and include some sample text ...

Comment: @guest I'd rather have some proper data to work with ...

Comment: if your DATE is always fixed length then you can do this in 2 steps, first remove all CR/LF from your text: find \r\n replace with nothing (using regexp replace option)
then search for ([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])  and replace with \r\n\1 (using REGEXP REPLACE)

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file is exported from excel, an easier way is [Find and Replace Line Break](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/05/28/find-and-replace-line-breaks-in-excel/) with Space then export again.

If you have no access to original excel, then in notepad++ replaces in extended search mode `\r\n` to `\r` then `\n` to `space` then `\r` back to `\r\n`.

The reason it works is excel delimits row with `\r\n`. Single `\n` must have originated from cell data.